# Poedit and WordpPress: unwanted result in the translation of HTML tags

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, poedit

I have to translate some sections of a WordPress theme and I am faced with a difficulty, in practice:

The php source is the following

```
jQuery( '.login.login-action-lostpassword.bb-login #login > p.message' ).html( '<?php _e( '<div>Forgot your password?</div><p class="message">Please enter your email address. You will receive an email with instructions on how to reset your password.</p>', 'buddyboss-theme' ); ?>' );
```

and the corresponding section of the .po that I have inserted (also with the help of the "Translation suggestions") is the following:

```
#. Marcello
msgid "<div>Forgot your password?</div><p class=\"message\">Please enter your email address. You will receive an email with instructions on how to reset your password.</p>"
msgstr "<div>Hai dimenticato la password?</div><p class=\"message\">Inserisci il tuo indirizzo email. Riceverai un'e-mail con le istruzioni su come reimpostare la password.</p>"
```

Unfortunately, the compilation of the .mo after the intervention produces "disastrous" effects on the generated page, as from the 2 pictures

[image]

[image]

**More details**

I went to check how the sentence had been translated into other languages ​​and copied the following section from the French .po

```
msgid ""
"<div>Forgot your password?</div><p class=\"message\">Enter your email "
"address. You will receive a link to create a new password via email.</p>"
msgstr ""
"<div>Vous avez oublié votre mot de passe ?</div><p class=\"message\">Entrez "
"votre adresse e-mail. Vous recevrez un lien pour créer un nouveau mot de "
"passe par courriel.</p>"
```

Unfortunately in this case the string is not found and the page exits without translation.
Should I ask the theme creator to change the code, or is there a way to translate?

Comment: _“and the corresponding section of the .po that I have inserted”_ - are you saying that you are editing those files _manually_? That sounds like a very bad idea to begin with.

Comment: Some strings are not present in the  original .po, so I added the msgid "" and msgstr "" lines. 

Then I edited them using Poedit, It's this not possible?
All other added strings, exept this one, are working

Answer (score 0):

Translation really can't do such things and it *really* can't insert different text from what you typed — as your screenshot shows.

Clearly the screenshot does not match the *actual* content of the translation file (the text differs), so the most likely explanation is that the actually used translation has broken markup in it. Double-check it. Make sure you don't use typographic quotes etc.

Comment: Are you then telling me that the string is not translatable?
What do you mean by "typographic quotes"?